# Define a colormap for each set of values in an array

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have an array with 3 set of values ​​that I want to color:

- for values between 0 and 1 (`np.ma.masked_array(array, array > 1.)`) I want a gradient (`cmap = cm.Greens` for example)
- for values ​​equal to 2 (`np.ma.masked_array(array, array != 2.)`) I want the color to be red
- for values ​​equal to 3 (`np.ma.masked_array(array, array != 3.)`) I want the color to be gray

Should I define a colormap for each set of values and then merge all of them into one colormap? If so how do I proceed?

On this website (http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps) I found that options like `ListedColormap` or `LinearSegmentedColormap` might be helpful but I don't really know how to use it to get what I want.

**EDIT:** I made that and it doesn't work because I don't know how to use `ListedColormap` and `LinearSegmentedColormap` to get what I want

```
from random import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

n=11

tab = np.array([[random() for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)])
tab[1,2] = 2.
tab[3,4] = 2.
tab[5,6] = 3.
tab[7,8] = 3.

values1 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab > 1.)
values2 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab != 2.)
values3 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab != 3.)

colors1 = cm.Greens
colors2 = ListedColormap(['red'], 'indexed')
colors3 = ListedColormap(['gray'], 'indexed')

colors = np.vstack((colors1, colors2, colors3))
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

print plt.imshow(tab, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none")
```

Comment: You are correct in that you would best use `ListedColormap` (if values are discrete) or `LinearSegmentedColormap` (if values are continuous). As long as noone knows what your problem in implementing either of those is, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I edited my question, what I want to do seems to be a mix of both discrete and continuous values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ListedColormap` is best be used for discrete values, while a `LinearSegmentedColormap` is more easily created for continuous values. Especially, if an existent colormap shall be used, a `LinearSegmentedColormap` is a good choice.

The `LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("name", colors)` expects a list of colors ,`colors` (not a colormap!). This list can be created using an existent colormap, e.g. `greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))` with 50 colors from that map. For another color to cover the same range we can add the same number of colors, e.g. all being red or gray.

An example is below.

```
from random import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm

n=11
tab = np.array([[random() for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)])
tab[1,2] = 2.
tab[3,4] = 2.
tab[5,6] = 3.
tab[7,8] = 3.

values1 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab > 1.)
values2 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab != 2.)
values3 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab != 3.)

# 50 values for later use from 0 to 1
greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))
# 25 values for later use from 1 to 1.5
greensfill = cm.Greens(np.ones(25))
# 50 values red for later use from 1.5 to 2.5 
red = [(1,0,0,1)]*len(greens)
# 50 values gray for later use from 2.5 to 3.5 
gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*len(greens)

colors = np.vstack((greens, greensfill, red, gray))
# in total we now have 175 colors in the colormap
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

#we now map those 175 colors to the range between 0 and 3.5
im = plt.imshow(tab, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", vmin=0, vmax=3.5)
cb = plt.colorbar(im)
cb.set_ticks([0,1,2,3])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here, the colors from the list are equally spaced in the final colormap.

An alternative could be to specify colors accompanied with the respective values.

```
colors = [(0, "white"), (1./3.5, "green"), (1.5/3.5, "green"),
          (1.501/3.5, "red"), (2.5/3.5, "red"), (2.501/3.5, "gray"), (1, "gray") ]
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation !

Comment: Is it possible to adapt this answer for a case with negative values? In my case:

colors = [(-0.100/0.099, "green"), (0.100/0.269, "blue"), (0.270/0.439, "yellow"),
          (0.440/0.659, "orange"), (0.660 /1.300, "red")]

error: 
    ValueError: data mapping points must start with x=0 and end with x=1