# Matplotlib: how to cut a colorbar in 2 or more?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have an array with 3 set of values:

- values between 0 and 1 (green gradient)
- values ​​equal to 2 (red)
- values ​​equal to 3 (gray)

Thanks to this post ([Define a colormap for each set of values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605051/define-a-colormap-for-each-set-of-values-in-an-array)) I was able to get this code:

```
from random import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm

n=11
tab = np.array([[random() for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)])
tab[1,2] = 2.
tab[3,4] = 2.
tab[5,6] = 3.
tab[7,8] = 3.

values1 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab > 1.)
values2 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab != 2.)
values3 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab != 3.)

# 50 values for later use from 0 to 1
greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))
# 25 values for later use from 1 to 1.5
greensfill = cm.Greens(np.ones(25))
# 50 values red for later use from 1.5 to 2.5 
red = [(1,0,0,1)]*len(greens)
# 50 values gray for later use from 2.5 to 3.5 
gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*len(greens)

colors = np.vstack((greens, greensfill, red, gray))
# in total we now have 175 colors in the colormap
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

#we now map those 175 colors to the range between 0 and 3.5
im = plt.imshow(tab, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", vmin=0, vmax=3.5)
cb = plt.colorbar(im)
cb.set_ticks([0,1,2,3])

plt.show()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

**My question is:** can matplotlib get something like the image below (editing done with photoshop) by cutting the existing colormap into 3 separate colormap or something close?

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=75))
red = [(1,0,0,1)]*(len(greens)/2)
white = [(1,1,1,1)]*3
black = [(0,0,0,1)]*1
gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*(len(greens)/2)

colors = np.vstack((greens, black, white, black, red, black, white, black, gray))
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)
```

I modified the code and got what follows but it does not look nice and the indexes are in the wrong place:

[image]

Comment: Great idea (because I didn't see anything like that on the internet so I figured it would a little bit difficult) ! And how do I do to move the indexes where I want ?

Comment: @LoïcPoncin You can specify tick positions via `set_ticks` and tick labels via `set_ticklabels`. So you can achieve the ticks+labels of the right hand plot via `cb.set_ticks([0, 1.5, 2, 3]); cb.set_ticklabels(['0', '1', '2', '3'])`. However it sets the label `1` at position `1.5` so it actually invalidates the color bar. Also in your right hand plot (the photoshopped one) the red region spans from 1 to 2.5 and the gray region spans from 2.5 to 3.5 however they have the same size. Green spans a similar region as gray and a smaller region than red however it is the largest of the three.

Comment: Thank you. @a_guest yes I understand that it does not really correspond to the principle of the colorbar. In fact, I working on a school project about forest fires and in my animation the green gradient (between 0 and 1) corresponds to the capacity of the vegetation contained in a pixel to burn, the red pixels correspond to the burning trees and those in gray correspond to the trees that have burned and are in ashes. So the red and gray colors are rather there to legend the animation.

Comment: I think @MadPhysicist 's comment is very misleading. Of course it is possible to have many different colorbars in the same figure and in order to place them there, no subclassing is needed at all.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Thanks for pointing that out. I remember being part of a discussion about this a while back, but I did not know that the issue had been resolved. Removed my comment.

Comment: Well, even in version 1.4 this was possible (see e.g. [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/api/colorbar_only.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Don't change the colormap! This is the map that specifies your data, so if you change it, the data representation is different from what you initially targeted at.

What you can do is create 3 different colorbars, as shown below. Mind the difference: We have one single colormap, but 3 colorbars, which all show part of the one colormap.

[image]

```
from random import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import cm

n=11
tab = np.array([[random() for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)])
tab[1,2] = 2.
tab[3,4] = 2.
tab[5,6] = 3.
tab[7,8] = 3.

values1 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab > 1.)
values2 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab != 2.)
values3 = np.ma.masked_array(tab, tab != 3.)

# 50 values for later use from 0 to 1
greens = cm.Greens(np.linspace(0,1, num=50))
# 25 values for later use from 1 to 1.5
greensfill = cm.Greens(np.ones(25))
# 50 values red for later use from 1.5 to 2.5 
red = [(1,0,0,1)]*len(greens)
# 50 values gray for later use from 2.5 to 3.5 
gray = [(.5,.5,.5,1)]*len(greens)

colors = np.vstack((greens, greensfill, red, gray))
# in total we now have 175 colors in the colormap
mycmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('my_colormap', colors)

#we now map those 175 colors to the range between 0 and 3.5
im = plt.imshow(tab, cmap = mycmap, interpolation="none", vmin=0, vmax=3.5)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90, bottom=0.1)
cb1ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.85, 0.8, 0.035, 0.1])
cb2ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.85, 0.67, 0.035, 0.1])
cb3ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.035, 0.54])

plt.gcf().colorbar(im, cax=cb1ax, boundaries=[2.5,3.5], ticks=[3])
plt.gcf().colorbar(im, cax=cb2ax, boundaries=[1.5,2.5], ticks=[2])
plt.gcf().colorbar(im, cax=cb3ax, boundaries=np.linspace(0,1, num=100), ticks=[0,1])

plt.show()
```

---

**Edit:** Now it may happen that the colorbar doesn't sit tightly spaced to the image or even overlaps it. It may also happen that the three bars are larger in height than the image. In order to prevent this we can resize the bars and adjust their position, such that they would always look nice. Therefore the lower part of the script may be replaces by the following code.

```
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90, bottom=0.1)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
ax = plt.gca()

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.90, bottom=0.1)
cb1ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.85, 0.8, 0.035, 0.1])
cb2ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.85, 0.67, 0.035, 0.1])
cb3ax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0.85, 0.1, 0.035, 0.54])

plt.gcf().colorbar(im, cax=cb1ax, boundaries=[2.5,3.5], ticks=[3])
plt.gcf().colorbar(im, cax=cb2ax, boundaries=[1.5,2.5], ticks=[2])
plt.gcf().colorbar(im, cax=cb3ax, boundaries=np.linspace(0,1, num=100), ticks=[0,1])

def resize(event=None):
    s = 0.03
    pos = ax.get_position()
    smh = pos.height/8.; loh = pos.height*0.675
    w = 0.06*pos.width; 
    x0 = pos.x1+0.065*pos.width
    cb1ax.set_position([x0, pos.y0+loh+smh+2*s, w, smh])
    cb2ax.set_position([x0, pos.y0+loh+s,       w, smh])
    cb3ax.set_position([x0, pos.y0,             w, loh])

resize()
plt.connect("resize_event", resize)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Look at what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQAvH.png . How do I align the 3 colorbars correctly to the right of my figure and with the same size? I know that for a single colorbar it would have to be something like `divider = make_axes_locatable(axes)` and then `cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.2)`. And how to put the small traits beside the indexes outside the figure instead of the inside?

Comment: Do you want the ticks pointing outwards for the complete figure? Then `plt.rcParams["xtick.direction"] = "out"` at the top of your script would help. The divider will not work for 3 colorbars. What do you mean by "with the same size"? should they all be one third of the image height?

Comment: I mean I want the top and bottom of the set of colorars to be aligned with the top and bottom of the array. For example in you post the  colorbar is aligned correctly with the top and the bottom of the array but in the link I sent you it is not. Thanks for the ticks that's exactly what I want.

Comment: I think also in your image they are well aligned. Or do you mean this one pixel offset? That is probably an antialiasing problem. Once you shift the bars away from the main image, you won't see any difference anymore.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I put 0.92 instead of 0.85 in `add_axes` and I get that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwUDS.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137461/discussion-between-loic-poncin-and-importanceofbeingernest).